# if user did not enter integer value in comma separated series

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class CommaSepratedNumMax 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner san = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Integer> Al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String line;
    String[] lineVector;
    System.out.println("enter the series");
    line = san.nextLine();
    lineVector = line.split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<lineVector.length;i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Al.add(i,Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i]));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e )
        { 
            System.out.println(" ERROR: You did not enter a Ineger value");
            break;
        }
    }

    int max=Al.get(0);
    for(int i=0;i<Al.size();i++)
    {
        if (Al.get(i)>max)
            max=Al.get(i);
    } 
    System.out.println("max no in series is="+max);
}

}
```

if the user did not enter a integer value above code will give index out of bound exception and many more exception how to resolve these errors

Answer (score 3):

If `Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i])` throws an exception, you won't be adding an element to the `i`'th position of the List. Therefore, in the next iteration you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you try to add an element to the `i+1`'th position.

You don't have to specify the index when adding to the List.

Change :

```
Al.add(i,Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i]));
```

to

```
Al.add(Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i]));
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you don't need to loop by index and can use `Collections.max` for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

`AL`'s size is 0, since no integers have been given. But you are trying to access the first item (index 0). That's impossible as there are no items in the list.

Check if the list has any item before trying to get anything from it.

```
if (AL.size() > 0) {
    int max = Al.get(0);
}
```

Comment: above thing helps only when fist value is non integer if first value is integer and second value is character then it gives wrong output